# Purpose of level locking in WoW

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've read about level locking on several websites (e.g. [WoWWiki](http://www.wowwiki.com/Level_locking)), however, they focus on how instead of why. What is the purpose? If I level a character straight to 90 do I miss something that is impossible to make up?

Comment: Just as a non-relevant tip: Wowwiki is pretty outdated. [Wowpedia.org](http://Wowpedia.org) is usually the better option for more up to date information.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

People may want to lock a character into a specific PvP group. The PvP groups go from x0 - x4 or x5 - x9 (eg 10 - 14) so by locking to 10, 11, 12, 13, or 14 you stick in a particular group.

It's mostly done by people who are engaging in [twinking](http://twinking.net/), which is kitting a low level character out in the best, most expensive PvP gear available at that level and just playing a lot of PvP.

Taken from Nick Bayley's comment: Another reason why people level lock, although not as popular, is to do old dungeons/raids at the level they were meant to be done at. However, with the talent changes, glyphs and inflation of gear, they don't pose the same challenge as they did when they were current content.

Comment: Another reason why people level lock, although not as popular, is to do old dungeons/raids at the level they were meant to be done at. However, with the talent changes, glyphs and inflation of gear, they don't pose the same challenge as they did when they were current content.

Comment: Brackets were changed to span 5 levels each. [Source](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/1293872)

Comment: Something else I forgot. Patch 5.2 brought the following: Players in low-level Battlegrounds will have their effective level raised to the maximum level allowed in that Battleground bracket. Players’ base stats and spells are scaled accordingly, and are treated as the same level when determining hits, misses, and critical effect chance. A very good article on what effects it has had on twinking can be read [here](http://cynwise.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/on-the-broken-battleground-scaling-of-5-2/)

Comment: And a [follow-up article](http://cynwise.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/analysis-of-the-post-hotfix-5-2-battleground-scaling-changes/) to the one I posted, as Blizzard did hotfix some of the issues highlighted in the previous article.

Comment: I've edited my answer to take into account these two things, thanks both.

Comment: you can't do older raids below max level for that content. So 60 for old world, 70 for bc, 80 for wrath, 85 for cata and obviously 90 for pandaria. This aspect of raiding has never changed.

Comment: @Ravekner that got edited in without my input

Comment: Submitted an edit to fix the issue I had with that part of the answer.

Comment: The problem I have found to be the biggest issue for most PvE twink guilds is that the majority of the time they do not impose restrictions onto the guild members other than the level restriction. So you have a bunch of lvl 60 toons running around doing Old World raids with starter area BC gear(which has better stats per piece than any piece of gear dropped from lvl 60 raids, except perhaps tier 3 gear from Naxxramas which is no longer available as a lvl 60 raid).

Comment: @Ravekner you can do classic raids before level 60 and karazhan at level 68 http://www.wowwiki.com/Instances_by_level

Comment: yea sorry, but karazhan was and is a lvl 70 raid. you can't get into it at level 68, those lower level stats on the wiki page you linked to are the level you needed to be to start doing the quests that would let you get into the raid(also known as attunement quests). this misinterpretation would be like saying you could do heroic dungeons before max level. you can't and blizzard will never change that. its the way they built the game, end game content is just that, end game. meaning you have to be max level to even attempt it.

Answer (score 4):

The queue system doesn't allow you to sign up for random instance groups that are below your level. For example, if you want to get a specific item or get an achievement while in a group, you could freeze your level so that you can do it. This can be useful for more fully appreciating burning crusade and lich king heroics at the level they were designed for. It is possible to solo most instances and raids from previous expansions, but some of them are too hard, also, playing in a group can be more fun than playing alone.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure you don't out-level content if you're playing it for the first time. For example, I've recently come back to the game and am playing through the *Mists of Pandaria* expansion but have already hit level 90 and am only on the second zone. Locking at level 90 means the next expansion's content will still be level appropriate when I get to it.